# Best approach for getting the first differential in all directions and all elements

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, numpy

I would like to know what is the best approach to compute the first differential for a 2 dimensional array of n size in all directions possibly using python 2.7. 
Example
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
assuming I am calculating for element [1][1] in terms of computer or [2][2] in terms of mathematics which is 5

[5-1, 5-2, 5-3, 5-4, 5-5, 5-6, 5-7, 5-7, 5-9]

What approach should I use to do it? Any libraries/algorithms that I should look into?
How do I store the values and keep track of it?

Comment: So, the output would be a `9 x 9` array, right?

Comment: well in the above example the output will still be 3 x 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using NumPy

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
diff = A[1,1] - A
```

If you want the result as a 1D-array

```
diff = diff.reshape(-1)
```

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for large arrays and storage in terms of optimization.

Comment: @BiswadipPaul I'm not quite sure what you are asking. If you are wondering how the array is stored I am pretty sure NumPy has optimized this for you.

Comment: Thanks. Just wanted to know if there was any additional scope of optimization.